# Flutter projects for native mobile and desktop web browser

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-web, flutter-native

Can someone list a few projects on github where a Flutter application is being used as both:

1. a mobile **native** application (not a PWA)
2. as well as a normal web app viewable by desktop browsers?

My goal is to create a single codebase where I can deploy native Android/iOS mobile applications that can access device features like geofencing/bluetooth, while also being viewable by laptop/desktop users using a Safari/Chrome web browser.

thx!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/gihan667/flutter-web-responsive

u can see this

from youtube u can see the Responsive Web UI is always work on both paltform

but kip in mind most pob.dev lib are not for the same platform

Like The http is not sport for web cuze the browser will close link with http
and must have ssl on ur web server to make it work :)

wish that will help

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hntFZd5bddU&t=64s